# Magento 1.9.0.1 Keeps removing first item from cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, shopping-cart

When I add second item to cart it automatically removes the first item from the cart. I think it could possibly be a caching issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Magento doesn't use cache on cart and checkout. Can you give us more detail? any other customization or module which can create issue?